# Prove the linear operator $T:L^2(a,b)\to L^2(a,b) $, $Tf(x)=\int_a^b K(x,y)f(y)dy$ with $x \in [a,b]$ is well-defined

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

**Let $T:L^2(a,b)\to L^2(a,b) $, such that $Tf(x)=\int_a^b K(x,y)f(y)dy$ with $x \in [a,b]$ and $K \in L^2((a,b)\times (a,b))$**

My try:
$ K(x,y)\in L^2((a,b)\times(a,b))$ means $\int_a^b\int_a^b|K(x,y)|^2dxdy < +\infty\tag 1$

Taking $f \in L^2(a,b)$, which means that  $\int_a^b|f(x)|^2dx < +\infty\tag 2$

I have to prove that $Tf \in L^2(a,b)$, which means that
$$\int_a^b|Tf(x)|^2dx < +\infty \tag 3$$

$$\int_a^b|\int_a^b K(x,y)f(y)dy|^2dx < +\infty$$
$$\int_a^b(\int_a^b K(x,y)f(y)dy)(\int_a^b K(x,z)f(z)dz)^*dx < +\infty$$
$$\int_a^b\int_a^b\int_a^b K(x,y)f(y) K^*(x,z)f^*(z)dydzdx < +\infty$$

Basically I have to go from (1)and (2) to (3) or any of its equivalent expressions.I don't know what to do next if  this is even the right approach. I'd really appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, and just need to invoke Holder's inequality:

$\int_a^b \left|\int_a^bK(x,y)f(y)dy\right|^2dx\leq \int_a^b\|K(x,\cdot)\|^2_2\|f\|_2^2dx\leq \|f\|_2^2 \|K(\cdot,\cdot)\|_2^2<\infty$

Comment: So you are  taking the 1-norm on the right-hand side of $\int_a^bK(x,y)f(y)dy$?

Comment: Could you explain last step?, I don't get what happened with the integral . And also how to use the dots instead of variables

Comment: For the last step, write down the exact definition of the 2-norm on $[a,b]\times [a,b]$. The dots help to show which variable is being integrated in the norm, and which is held fixed.